# Rewrite QGIS project by standalone PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I have a QGIS project with layers were imported from cad and I am trying to use standalone pyqgis to rewrite this project and a new csv layer to it. But when I try to rewrite the project I get all layer show up in layer browser like this:

[image: layer browser]

but nothing show up in map browser.

Here is my code. Is there anyone please help me out with this?

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.extend([r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python',r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages'])
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\plugins'
os.environ['PATH'] += r';C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Qt5\bin'

sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python')
sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins')
sys.path.append(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing')

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtXml import *
def read_project():
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis', True)
    qgs=QgsApplication([], False)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()
    project=QgsProject.instance()
    project.read(r'D:\NTOU\REALTIMEMODEL\COMBINEDMETHOD\test_1.qgz')
    #print(project.fileName()) 
    project.write(r'D:\NTOU\REALTIMEMODEL\COMBINEDMETHOD\test_4.qgz')
    layers=QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()
    print(layers) 
    QgsApplication.exitQgis()
read_project()
```